# How to display ToolStripStatusLabel.Text using an array on mouseEnter

Tags: vb.net

I have an array of picture boxes with images. I want the status bar to change when the mouse enters the image. I am stuck on displaying the correct text when the mouse is over a pictureBox.

hr1StatusText is an array of text read from a text file. Everything works but I can't figure how to iterate through the text for the status bar.

The code below works displaying the text for all PB's as long as the index is changed. What I am looking for is to display hr1StatusText(0) for PB(0), hr1StatusText(1) for PB(1), etc.

```
Public Sub Tile_MouseEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.MouseEnter
    Dim TileMouse As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, PictureBox)
    ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = hr1StatusText(0)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

So something like:

```
Me.ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = hr1StatusText(Array.IndexOf(PB, TileMouse))
```

?

Edit: If they're not in an array, assign a `Tag` (through the Designer) to each `PictureBox` for the string you want to be displayed, and do this:

```
Me.ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = DirectCast(PB.Tag, String)
```

Comment: I get the error; Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox' to type 'System.Array'. code; ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = hr1StatusText(Array.IndexOf(sender, TileMouse))

Comment: @user1072536: So, `PB` isn't actually an array? What is it then? I got the impression from your question where you said `PB(0)`, `PB(1)`, etc. that `PB` was an array...

Comment: Yes, they are arrays. PictureBox array, ToolStripStatusLabel Array and a text array for the status labels.

Comment: @user1072536: If `PB` is an array, then my original code will work. Simply replace `PB` with the actual name of your array.

Comment: I get the error "Index was outside the bounds of the array." on mouse over of any PictureBox when using the picture array name.

Comment: @user1072536: Can I please see your code, then? The entire thing?

Comment: I have two forms and four modules but only one form and two modules are involved in this. However, there is over 1600 characters and it won't let me post it all.

Comment: @user1072536: Put it in some other website like in a GitHub Gist and post a link.

Comment: Entire Project - Visual Studio 2008 Standard - http://www.tomnobles.com/VB/DYNAMICMAP.ZIP

Comment: @user1072536: You never initialize the arrays with anything. You need to do so. Also, I take it you don't need 4,000 of them. Use a `List(Of t)` instead.

Comment: I don't understand. Everything works except for mouseOver of individual pictureBoxes. Refer to original post;  ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text will change by changing the index of hr1StatusText(0). However this will make the text the same for all pictureBoxes. Correct, I don't need 4,000, I planned to change that when I got things figured out.

Comment: @user1072536: I don't see how that's even working. Initialize your array with all the values and everything will work properly.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort.